# Uncaught Malformed table row, a cell is undefined. Unable to generate pdf in datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am receiving this error when there is no data available in datatable and when I click on the generate pdf option. I have used the pdfmake js for this.
All the other options are working properly like generate csv, excel etc but not the pdf generate function.

This is my working code for datatables

```
$('#listTable').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
  'copy', 'csv', 'excel', {
    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
    orientation: 'landscape',
    pageSize: 'LEGAL',
    customize: function ( doc ) {
      doc.content.splice( 1, 0, {
        margin: [ 0, 0, 0, 12 ],
        alignment: 'center',
      });
    }
  },
  {
    extend: 'print',
  }
  ],
  'paging': true,
  "pagingType": "full_numbers",
  "lengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
  'autoWidth'   : false,
  'stateSave' : true,
  scrollCollapse: true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Found out the solution. Set the body row array empty in **dataTables.buttons.js** so that no rows will be considered while the print action.

```
var body = [ rows ];
var body = [];
```

For more details visit this link : https://github.com/DataTables/Buttons/commit/912d605b7f65e05f28444742c62447e9fd72a972